# Ajax queries with Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I try to display a list of items in a table using Knockout JS. This is like a typical search interface, where the user types a query and the interface displays the list of results returned by the search engine. I first retrieve them from the server through an AJAX call and then try to bind them. This works for the first query very well. But when I try the second query (and subsequent queries), each result item is represented 10 times (duplicated), then for the 3rd query each item is displayed for like 30 times (and so on). Given below is the code.

```
<body >
<p>
  <input type="search" id="skynet-query" name="q" placeholder="scientific search" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" id="skynet-submit" value="Ignite!" onclick="getAttachments(document.getElementById('skynet-query').value)" />
</p>
<article data-bind="foreach: seats">   
        <h3>
            <input data-bind="attr:{value: papers().id }" type="checkbox" name="article-to-basket" />
            <a data-bind="attr:{href: papers().url }, text: papers().title"> </a>
        </h3>
        <address class="authors" data-bind="text: papers().authors"/>
</article>
</body>
```

Following is the Script part

```
<script>

 var array = new Array();

function getAttachments(keyword) {

  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "get-papers?q="+keyword+"&format=json&full-articles=true&kw-count=10&article-count=10&task-type=m1"
  });

  request.done(function (response) {

    for (i=0;i<response.articles.length; i++){
        array[i] = new PaperData(response.articles[i]);
    }
    ko.cleanNode(document);
    ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
    console.log("DONE");
  });

}

function PaperData(papers) {
    var self = this;
    self.papers = ko.observable(papers);
}

function ReservationsViewModel() {
    //var self = this;
    self.seats = ko.observableArray(array);

}

</script>
```

Can someone help me to find what's wrong with this code?

This is what my data-model looks like

```
 {
    articles: [
    {
    "is-saved": false,
    title: "title",
    abstract: "Abstract",
    date: "2005-01-01 00:00:00",
    "publication-forum": "forum",
    "publication-forum-type": "article",
    authors: "Authors",
    keywords: "keyword1, keyword2, keywordn",
    id: "4f5a318e573ce53e03000015"
    }
    ]

    }
```

Comment: Actually in the 3rd time each item was displayed 45 times :( very weird and I can't understand why

Comment: Your `array` is "global" and you are always adding items to and you never clear it...

Comment: Where do the `seats` come from? Your view model seems to be incomplete.

Comment: seats come from the array.function ReservationsViewModel() {
    //var self = this;
    self.seats = ko.observableArray(array);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to knockout is not quite right.

- Every value you display on the screen is supposed to be an observable that is tied into your view model.
- For example, input elements with names are unnecessary - the `value` binding takes care of updating the view model. You never have to address an `<input>` by name.
- Don't *ever* use inline event handlers like `onclick`. Not in Knockout and not anywhere else.
- Don't use global variables. Your problem comes from the use of a global `array` variable that in reality should be an observable array on your view model.
- Don't clear out everything and reconstruct your entire view model from scratch just because something changed. Knockout will handle any partial updates.

Here's an improved approach.

```
<p>
  <input type="search" data-bind="value: query" placeholder="scientific search" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" data-bind="click: getAttachments" />
</p>
<article data-bind="foreach: seats">   
    <h3>
        <input data-bind="value: id, checked: selected" type="checkbox" />
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a>
    </h3>
    <address class="authors" data-bind="text: authors"/>
</article>
```

and

```
function PaperData(data) {
    ko.utils.extend(this, data);
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
}
PaperData.create = function (data) {
    return new PaperData(data);
};

function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.query = ko.observable();
    self.seats = ko.observableArray();

    self.queryParams = {
        "q": self.query,
        "format": "json",
        "full-articles": true,
        "kw-count": 10,
        "article-count": 10,
        "task-type": "m1"
    };

    self.getAttachments = function () {
        $.get("get-papers", ko.toJS(self.queryParams))
        .then(function (response) {
            return ko.utils.arrayMap(response.articles, PaperData.create);
        })
        .done(self.seats);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Notes

- You can use `.then()` to transform Ajax response data on the fly.
- You can use `.done()` to write the transformed result into an observable.
- Making the `queryParams` a separate property of the view model allows you to dynamically tweak other query parameters just like shown with `"q"`.
- You can use `ko.utils.extend` to transfer properties from one object to another. Alternatively you could use the mapping plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer. I realized that I still haven't understood the concepts of Knockout right. I tried to replace my code with yours but got the following error.Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return id }"
Message: id is not defined  - This could be because the value id is not in the data so I replaced it with this.id then this error is gone but I got no results

Comment: Don't use any JavaScript code in your binding declarations. Things like `"value: function (){return id }"` should never happen. All calculations ought to happen in the view model, bindings should only contain property names. For debugging purposes, try to add `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>` to problematic template sections. This way you can inspect the actual object Knockout tries to work with in any context.

Comment: Of course I had to take a few guesses about your data model, since you did not show any JSON. I'm sure if you step through the code you'll be able to figure out how things should look like in your particular case.

Comment: I added the datamodel. I did not add any javascript code. The error came in <input data-bind="value: id, checked: selected" type="checkbox" /> It says the id is not defined. This came to all the other variables I used like title, authors. When i tried this.id the error goes, but still I get no results on the display.

Comment: Sorry, but what you have added does not even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed the closing ]. It should compile now. I would get 10 articles like that in return from the server.

Comment: No, it does not. It's neither syntactically valid JSON nor syntactically valid JavaScript. It's not indented correctly and `url` is also missing. Please be more thorough with your code if you want to produce working results.

Comment: Once these errors are fixed my code runs unchanged. http://jsfiddle.net/fLca2/ (Next time you set up the fiddle, it would have been your duty anyway.)

Comment: Thank you so much Tomalak. Your sample code in fiddle helped me a lot. The problem was .done(self.seats); did not work some how. So I removed that and added .then(function (response) {
                      self.seats(ko.utils.arrayMap(response.articles, PaperData.create));
        }) And then it worked. Thank you for saving my day.